# Definition prototype for a function accepting an empty Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net

I want to do something using a lambda expression and it doesn't use any parameters, I know I can use the form `() => foo()` but I can't figure out what to do at the function prototype where the lambda is passed as a parameter

Here's the code

```
class c {
    public static void Main() {
        Bar(() => Console.WriteLine("Hey"));
    }
    public static void Bar(what_goes_here foo) {
        foo(); //Should print "Hey"
    }
}
```

Comment: `Action` would go there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a value.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you're looking for `Action`:

```
public static void Bar(Action foo)
{
    foo();
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx)